# Store permanently the fetched states and city name to a file

Tags: javascript, php, html, performance

I have a php code that fetch the states and cities for user to select, and it is every time fetching it from `db` and it is affecting my page load time. so I want to know is it possible that I store that code to a separate file say for example `cityname.php`, and then output its result to a static file say `citname-out.php`. and I get the result from there so it will increase load time. so what I want is if I run the page like `www.domain.com/citename.php`, than it permanently store the fetched result to the file `citename-out.php`. so I can easily use the file `cityname-out.php`.

If I have a code like the one below in the file `cityname.php`

```
<div class="statenames">
     <?php if(osc_count_list_regions() > 0 ) { ?>
     <div class="box location">
          <h3><strong><?php _e("Location", 'modern'); ?></strong></h3>
          <ul>
          <?php while(osc_has_list_regions() ) { ?>
              <li>
                  <a href="<?php echo osc_list_region_name(); ?>"><?php echo osc_list_region_name(); ?></a> 
                  <em>(<?php echo osc_list_region_items(); ?>)</em>
              </li>
          <?php } ?>
          </ul>
     </div>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Then how to store its output to a file permanently

Comment: Take a look at http://www.phpfastcache.com/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a Cache system.

There are a ton of them out there. Top google result points to: http://www.phpfastcache.com/

which seems easy enough to implement. If you are using a php framework you may have cache functionality available to you out of the box already

Comment: putting the code inside it as mentions will give the result right. or i have to do any thing else

Comment: That should be all it needs. If you have trouble implementing it I would post a followup question